# Auth Roles in blazor server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

i'm using the latest dot net 8 and blazor app as a server side rendering. I'm trying to add role auth to the app. I've got my azure web app and app registration and authentication working. I added roles and assigned them to my user in entra id. When i step through my code i can see the `roles` claim and it has my custom role added to it. when i try to use the `<AuthorizeView Roles="Spec.Read"><p>you have spec.read role</p>` it never shows. here's what I got so far:

*myComponent.razor*

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name</p> @*shows my e-mail as expected*@
    <p>Roles: @roles</p> @*shows the roles that is populated in the code section as expected. this includes "Spec.Read" *@
    <AuthorizeView Roles="Spec.Read" Context="childContext">
        <p>you are a spec reader</p> @* this never shows up *@
    </AuthorizeView>
</AuthorizeView>
...
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationState{ get; set; }
    
    string roles = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        SpecList = await CosmosDataSource.GetSpecList();

        if(authenticationState is not null)
        {
            var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)(await authenticationState).User?.Identity;
            var claims = userIdentity.Claims;
            roles = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "roles").Select(x => x.Value).Aggregate((prev, next) => $"{prev}; {next}");
        }

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

here is my program.cs snippet that i use to add ME ID (Microsoft Entra ID) and this seems to work.
*program.cs*

```
...
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
    AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options=>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
...
```

so how can I use my role claims to be used in the `<AuthorizationView Roles=...` section in my blazor component?

Also, I could be doing Auth completely wrong. this is my first time implementing auth and i'm trying to follow the MS docs but there is a bit of inconsistency throughout the docs and frameworks and net versions.

*picture showing the roles working in the blazor*

[image: picture of the roles working]

*debugger showing the roles claim*

[image: Debugger showing the roles claim]

EDIT:

I've updated my program cs add authentication to be the bellow snippet:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MicrosoftOidc")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("MicrosoftOidc", oidcOptions =>
    {
        oidcOptions.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess);
        oidcOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        oidcOptions.Authority = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"];
        oidcOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        oidcOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
        oidcOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        oidcOptions.MapInboundClaims = false;
        oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name;
        oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(
            oidcOptions.Authority,
            oidcOptions.Backchannel).Validate;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

however I'm still getting the same result. I've tried changing the RoleClaimType to be "roles" as well with no chnage. the `JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap` has both role and roles defined but both point to the same role schema

Comment: just as Taco mentioned,The AuthorizeView  component would read role from ClaimTypes.Role instead of "roles","roles" would be mapped to ClaimTypes.Role by default ,it seems that something got wrong with your claim mapping,you could call JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap to check the mapping dictionary in .Net 8

Comment: inspecting that the defaultInboundClaimTypeMap like you suggested produced these two items
`{[role, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role]}, {[roles, http://schemas.microsof.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role]}`
along with other values of course but these were the only two about roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the RoleClaimType? Because the default is `ClaimTypes.Role` (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`) but you use `roles`.

```
oidcOptions.MapInboundClaims = false;
oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name;
oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/blazor-web-app-with-oidc?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=without-bff-pattern

Comment: i tried this with no luck. I updated my question with your solution in context incase i implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like you are missing an s: `RoleClaimType = "role";`  But you select by `x.Type == "roles"` with an s

Comment: okay thanks. I had tried that and then relaunched my app from VS. but i was still logged in and i guess didn't pickup the roles. I tried with a new private browser and it worked. thanks. Can you update your answer to have "roles" and i'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: Done, I had indeed the same mistake in my answer.